# C++ workaround for doubles as template parameters

Tags: c++, templates

I know that doubles can't be template parameters so I'm looking for another way to create a function with several parameters. My current (obviously wrong) code looks like this:

```
template<double B1, double B2, double B3, double C1, double C2, double C3>
    double sellmeier(const double wavelength) {
        double refractive_index_sq = 1;
        double lambda_sq = std::pow(wavelength, 2);
        refractive_index_sq += B1*lambda_sq/(lambda_sq-C1);
        refractive_index_sq += B2*lambda_sq/(lambda_sq-C2);
        refractive_index_sq += B3*lambda_sq/(lambda_sq-C3);
        return refractive_index_sq;
    }
```

Is there a way to create a function that takes several non integral type parameters and one argument without making every parameter an argument too?

Comment: It depends what you want to use it for.  You could make a factory that creates `std::function` objects at runtime, for example, if you don't need those `double` arguments to be compile-time constants.  You could improve the question by showing how you intend to use your function (even better, create a [mcve] that demonstrates your objective).

Comment: What's your compiler?  The big ones like Intel's compilers and GCC (and I'm assuming Clang as well) can do some pretty ridiculous constant propagation and folding.  Just turn those template parameters into regular old function parameters, enter your constants, and you'll be fine.  This makes sense if you consider that those compilers have to optimize C and Fortran, languages which don't have C++ template parameters.

Comment: It turns out a factory was exactly what I needed for my needs as I don't need the values at compile time. I somehow just thought: Parameters = Template usage in this case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What You want here is a *policy class* which will supply your function with the required values (`SpecificConstants`).

```
struct SpecificConstants
{
    static constexpr double b1 { 0.6961663 };
    static constexpr double b2 { 0.4079426 };
    static constexpr double b3 { 0.8974794 };
    static constexpr double c1 { 0.0684043 * 0.0684043 };
    static constexpr double c2 { 0.1162414 * 0.1162414 };
    static constexpr double c3 { 9.896161 * 9.896161 };
};
```

Your function will only require this policy class (`Constants`)

```
template< typename Constants >
double sellmeier( const double wavelength )
{
    double refractive_index_sq = 1;
    double lambda_sq           = std::pow( wavelength, 2 );
    refractive_index_sq += Constants::b1 * lambda_sq / ( lambda_sq - Constants::c1 );
    refractive_index_sq += Constants::b2 * lambda_sq / ( lambda_sq - Constants::c2 );
    refractive_index_sq += Constants::b3 * lambda_sq / ( lambda_sq - Constants::c3 );
    return refractive_index_sq;
}
```

Then, the function can be called like this:

```
sellmeier< SpecificConstants >( 2.0 );
```

Answer (score 1):

In c++14 you can do the following, shown with one parameter for brevity's sake:

```
constexpr double GetB1(int b1Index)
{
    switch (b1Index)
    {
        case 0: return 1.2345;
        case 1: return 2.3456;
        default: return 3.4567;
    }
}

template<int B1Index>
    double obviouslyNotSellmeier(const double wavelength) {
        return wavelength * GetB1(B1Index);
    }

obviouslyNotSellmeier<1>(0.123)
```

Though it becomes very unfriendly to the caller.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a way to create a function that takes several non integral type parameters and one argument without making every parameter an argument too?

I don't know if it's a good idea but... yes, I suppose you can wrap your floating points values as `static` constant inside `struct`'s.

Starting from C++11 (`constexpr`) you can simply define

```
struct X1 { static constexpr double value { 1.2 }; };
struct X2 { static constexpr double value { 2.3 }; };
struct X3 { static constexpr double value { 3.4 }; };
struct Y1 { static constexpr double value { 4.5 }; };
struct Y2 { static constexpr double value { 5.6 }; };
struct Y3 { static constexpr double value { 6.7 }; };
```

pass they as template parameter to `sellmeier()`

```
sellmeier<X1, X2, X3, Y1, Y2, Y3>(1.0);
```

and use the `value` of types inside `sellmeier()`

```
template <typename B1, typename B2, typename B3,
          typename C1, typename C2, typename C3>
double sellmeier (const double wavelength)
 {
   double refractive_index_sq = 1;
   double lambda_sq = std::pow(wavelength, 2);
   refractive_index_sq += B1::value*lambda_sq/(lambda_sq-C1::value);
   refractive_index_sq += B2::value*lambda_sq/(lambda_sq-C2::value);
   refractive_index_sq += B3::value*lambda_sq/(lambda_sq-C3::value);
   return refractive_index_sq;
 }
```

Before C++11 (no `constexpr` available) the syntax, to define the wrapping structs, is a little more annoying: you have to initialize the `const` value outside of the body of the structs

```
struct X1 { static double const value; };
struct X2 { static double const value; };
struct X3 { static double const value; };
struct Y1 { static double const value; };
struct Y2 { static double const value; };
struct Y3 { static double const value; };

double const X1::value = 1.2;
double const X2::value = 2.3;
double const X3::value = 3.4;
double const Y1::value = 4.5;
double const Y2::value = 5.6;
double const Y3::value = 6.7;
```

Comment: @RobertAndrzejuk - one `struct` for every different `double` value; obviously zillions of other solutions are possible; maybe a single `struct` with a `constexpr` method as the `GetB1()` from the Rotem's solution, and six integer index as template parameter.

Answer (score 0):

As I don't need the parameters at compile time I realized a functor is the better/correct solution:

```
struct sellmeier {
    sellmeier(double B1, double B2, double B3, double C1, double C2, double C3) :
            B1(B1), B2(B2), B3(B3), C1(C1), C2(C2), C3(C3) {}
        double operator()(const double wavelength) {
            double refractive_index_sq = 1;
            double lambda_sq = std::pow(wavelength, 2);
            refractive_index_sq += B1 * lambda_sq / (lambda_sq - C1);
            refractive_index_sq += B2 * lambda_sq / (lambda_sq - C2);
            refractive_index_sq += B3 * lambda_sq / (lambda_sq - C3);
            return refractive_index_sq;
        }
    private:
        double B1, B2, B3, C1, C2, C3;
};

//functor with sellmeier coefficients for fused quartz
auto sellmeier_fused_quartz = sellmeier(0.6961663, 0.4079426, 0.8974794, 0.0684043*0.0684043, 0.1162414*0.1162414, 9.896161*9.896161);
```

Answer (score 0):

> As I don't need the parameters at compile time I realized a functor is the better/correct solution

In this case, if you can use C++11, you can simply write a lambda

```
#include <cmath>

int main ()
 {
   auto B1=0.6961663;
   auto B2=0.4079426;
   auto B3=0.8974794;
   auto C1=0.0684043*0.0684043;
   auto C2=0.1162414*0.1162414;
   auto C3=9.896161*9.896161;

   auto sellmeier = [=] (double const wavelength)
    {
      double refractive_index_sq = 1;
      double lambda_sq = std::pow(wavelength, 2);
      refractive_index_sq += B1*lambda_sq/(lambda_sq-C1);
      refractive_index_sq += B2*lambda_sq/(lambda_sq-C2);
      refractive_index_sq += B3*lambda_sq/(lambda_sq-C3);
      return refractive_index_sq;
    };

   sellmeier(1.0);
 }
```

Starting from C++14, you can simplify (IMHO) as follows

```
#include <cmath>

int main ()
 {
   auto sellmeier = [B1=0.6961663,
                     B2=0.4079426,
                     B3=0.8974794,
                     C1=0.0684043*0.0684043,
                     C2=0.1162414*0.1162414,
                     C3=9.896161*9.896161] (double const wavelength)
    {
      double refractive_index_sq = 1;
      double lambda_sq = std::pow(wavelength, 2);
      refractive_index_sq += B1*lambda_sq/(lambda_sq-C1);
      refractive_index_sq += B2*lambda_sq/(lambda_sq-C2);
      refractive_index_sq += B3*lambda_sq/(lambda_sq-C3);
      return refractive_index_sq;
    };

   sellmeier(1.0);
 }
```

Comment: This solution has a drawback. It is not a very "generic" - if somebody wants to reuse this function, they have to copy the whole function with the constants.

Comment: @RobertAndrzejuk - No. Capturing external variables by copy (the `[=]`) there is non need to copy the constants. You can simply transmit the lambda `sellmeier`.